# wordpress pagenation nav links redirecting to 404 in custom post type template

Tags: php, wordpress

```
     <?php
/*
Template Name: All Blog Post Custom Template
*/
?>
<?php
/**`enter code here`
 * @author madars.bitenieks
 * @copyright 2013
 */
ini_set('display_error',1);
get_header(); 
$page_idd = get_the_ID();
global $post;
//print_r($_GET);exit;
$mt_comment=get_post_meta($post->ID, "madza_comment", true); 
$mt_layout = get_post_meta($post->ID, "layout_positions", true);

$mt_float_layout = "";
$mt_float_sidebar = "";

if ($mt_layout == "left") {

    $mt_float_layout = "floatright";
    $mt_float_sidebar = "floatleft";
}

$more = 0;

?>

<div class="row">

    <div class="span<?php if ($mt_layout != "full") { echo "8 "; } else {  echo "12 "; } echo $mt_float_layout; ?> ">

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

                            <?php the_content( __( '<div class="reed_more">Reed More &raquo;</div><div></div>', 'madza_translate' ) ); ?>

                           <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'madza_translate' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>

                           <div class="clear"></div>

                    </div><!--END POST -->

                    <?php if($mt_comment=='Yes'){ comments_template( '', true );  }?>

                <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();  ?>

    </div>
                                                            <!-- code for showing all blog post -->
        <div class="rpwe-block" style="">
            <ul class="rpwe-ul">
                <?php 
                $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                set_query_var('page',$paged);
                $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
                'post_type' => 'blog',
                'posts_per_page' => 2,
                'orderby'=> 'menu_order',
                'paged' => $paged
                ) );
                ?>
                <?php if ($the_query->have_posts()) : ?>
                    <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <li class="rpwe-clearfix"> 
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                                <?php
                                add_image_size('custom-size', 180, 150);
                                the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
                                ?>
                                <h3 class="rpwe-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                            </a>
                            <span class="rpwe-time published"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>                                                              
                            <div class="rpwe-summary">
                                <?php echo substr(get_the_content(), 0, 100) . "..."; ?>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><p>Read More</p></a>
                            </div> 
                        <?php
                    endwhile;
                    ?>
                        <div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Newer posts');?></div>
                        <div class="nav-next alignright"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts &raquo;', $the_query->max_num_pages ); ?></div>
                        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            <?php   else :
                    ?>
                    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>       
            </ul>

        </div>


    <?php if ($mt_layout != "full") { ?>

        <div class="span4 <?php echo $mt_float_sidebar; ?> "><?php if( !($page_idd == 17169 or $page_idd == 17170) ){get_sidebar();} ?></div>

    <?php } ?>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

i have created custom post type named Bolg using CPT(custom post type) plugin. and and i copied page.php content to my new file named blog-page.php and then copy my code to display all blog post with pagenation on that page till here everything works file. but if i click to pagenation nav links (prev or next) then wordpress redirects me to 404(page not found) on    'localhost/mysite.com/blog/' is ok url but after clicking it redirect me to  , 'localhost/mysite.com/blog/page/2' which shows 404 error, means wordpress redirect me to somewhere else not on my orginal page, even is set this page to call custom template in wp admin panel. please help me how to resolve it.

Comment: try to update permalink once and check

Comment: actually i am new to wordpress please tell me what setting to permalinks should do.

Comment: Just go to your `Dashboard --> Settings --> Permalinks` and hit `Save`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to Admin panel dashboard
2. Go to settings >> permalinks
3. update your permalinks.

Comment: thanks for replying me ...but there are 3 section to update permalinks which one to update and how to update please provide me some details

Comment: i did it but not helped still have same problem. redirects me to localhost/blog/page/2 but shows 404 error.

Comment: your above code is proper..do one thing update permalink to default and check once

Comment: Thanks you very much....it worked fine and you saved my time. but to default permalink setting it breaks my site's url structure means it should be "localhost/mysite.com/blog" but it is like "http://localhost/mysite.com/?p=123" please suggest me about it or may be i can do it from .htaccess file?.
Thank you once again.

Comment: yes have you setup htaccess?. Pl tick correct to accept answer if helpful.

Comment: ya i clicked on correct and its green now. Ya i updated my .htaccess file and now everything working fine. thanks once again!!